# How does this loop work and what's its purpose?

Tags: c++11

I found code that used for loop like below :

```
//// Code
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++);
//// Code
```

I don't understand what that do as there is `;` at the end without a code block enclosed in braces `{}` for execution during the loop.

How that work in this case and what could be its purpose?

Comment: it's an empty loop then. maybe a typo?

Comment: It's either an error or sheep counting (busy wait) in a very bad code

Comment: It just works - the 'i' gets incremented MAX times, though it does almost nothing to the outer world, slows down your code

Comment: Why the downvote on this question? I don't see anything wrong with it. If we keep downvoting such question then `for(;;);` should also be considered as a bad question.

Answer (score 3):

It is a normal `for` loop that just does nothing in its body. In order to illustrate this in a better way here is how you can format it a little bit better so that you can see how it works:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
   // Just chillin...
}
```

The `while` representation of this loop is

```
int i = 0;
while(i < MAX)
{
  i++;
}
```

You can move the incrementing step of the `for` loop to make it look like it's doing something:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; )
{
   i++;
}
```

And infinite `for` loop can easily be written as follows:

```
for(;;);
```

Here even the initialization of the loop counter along with the termination condition and the incrementation step are omitted.

I do agree with @StenSoft - this is often an indicator that someone is trying to simulate some work. However the huge flow in doing something like this in this particular way is that it is very dependent on how fast your computer is. If you have a slow machine a loop of 10000 cycles might be a lot but if you have a relatively modern one this loop will be eaten up like it's nothing.

If work is to be simulated use a `sleep` function or whatever your platform and the library you are using provides.

Examples:

- [sleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) for POSIX.1-2001 conform systems
- [sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows using the Windows API

It is important to notice that not all sleep functions have the same time unit so one has to be careful and learn how the passed argument is interpreted - milliseconds, seconds etc.

Some additional examples on empty block statements:

```
if(SOME_CONDITION);
```

or

```
if(SOME_CONDITION);
else; // This might cause a warning if -Wempty-body is enabled
```

or even

```
int a = 0;
switch(a)
{
  case 0:
    break;
}
```

The body of a for, while etc. is considered correct if it follows the language's grammar. Whether it does something or not that is a completely different question.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop in C++ doesn't need a code block--a single statement will suffice. In particular, `;` is a perfectly fine statement which does nothing. So this loop does nothing `MAX` number of times. Most compilers probably have the ability to remove the no-op loop altogether, depending on optimization flags.

Answer (score 1):

In this case:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++);
```

this `for` loop just increments `i` till it's smaller than the value `MAX` and then the execution proceeds to the next line.

Thus, this `for` loop does nothing more than slowing the execution of the program.

Regarding the semicolon `;`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
    // execute a statement;
}
```

could be written as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){ // execute a statement; }
```

which could be witten as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) // execute a statement;
```

and when **there is no statement for execution**:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++);
```